# I keep gettint the error expected construcotr,destructor or type conversion before = token

Tags: arduino-uno, temperature-sensor

```
#include <dht.h>
dht DHT;
#define DHT11_PIN 2     // what pin we're connected to  // DHT 11 

String TextForSms ;
String humidity = " Humidity: %";
String temperature = "   Temperature";
String sign = " *C";
char fromc;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
  int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  float h = DHT.humidity;
  float t = DHT.temperature; 
  delay(2000);
  }

  TextForSms = TextForSms + t + "," + h + ","; 
Serial.println(TextForSms); 
     TextForSms = ""; 
   delay(1000);
```

Comment: Please add a sentence to describe the question.  What are you actually asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This whole section:

```
  TextForSms = TextForSms + t + "," + h + ","; 
Serial.println(TextForSms); 
     TextForSms = ""; 
   delay(1000);
```

is outside a block. Code must be inside a block.

There are strict rules governing what can go where in a C or C++ program. I suggest you learn them.